# Is this Codeigniter Paypal IPN Library & Controller safe enough from any malicious behaviour?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am simply asking if this code below is safe enough from unathorized fake IPN requests and etc?
Would appreciate if you point what could be improved or if its good the way it is since it works perfectly already. Thank you a lot for spending your time to answer to my question.

> Paypal_Lib.php file | Validate_IPN() function

```
    function validate_ipn()
    {
        // parse the paypal URL
        $url_parsed = parse_url($this->paypal_url);       

        // generate the post string from the _POST vars aswell as load the
        // _POST vars into an arry so we can play with them from the calling
        // script.
        $post_string = '';   
        if (isset($_POST))
        {
            foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value)
            {       // str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $value)
                    // put line feeds back to CR+LF as that's how PayPal sends them out
                    // otherwise multi-line data will be rejected as INVALID

                $value = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $value);
                $this->ipn_data[$field] = $value;
                $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)).'&';

            }
        }

$post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command

        // open the connection to paypal
        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com',"443",$err_num,$err_str,30); 
        if(!$fp)
        {
            // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message
            // will be in the log.
            $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errnum: $errstr";
            $this->log_ipn_results(false);       
            return false;
        } 
        else
        { 
            // Post the data back to paypal
            fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
            fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n"); 
            fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
            fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n"); 
            fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
            fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n"); 

            // loop through the response from the server and append to variable
            while(!feof($fp))
                $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 

            fclose($fp); // close connection
        }

        if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response))
        {
            // Valid IPN transaction.
            $this->log_ipn_results(true);
            return true;         
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the log for details.
            $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.';
            $this->log_ipn_results(false);  
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**

> Paypal.php controller function to handle the IPN. It checks if its
>   validated and if the amount is 197 USD in this example.

```
    function ipn()
    {
        // Payment has been received and IPN is verified.  This is where you
        // update your database to activate or process the order, or setup
        // the database with the user's order details, email an administrator,
        // etc. You can access a slew of information via the ipn_data() array.

        // Check the paypal documentation for specifics on what information
        // is available in the IPN POST variables.  Basically, all the POST vars
        // which paypal sends, which we send back for validation, are now stored
        // in the ipn_data() array.

        // For this example, we'll just email ourselves ALL the data.

// IT'S ONLY TEST DATA BELOW!
        $item = '507';
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency2 = '197';
        if (($payment_currency === $payment_currency2) && ($this->paypal_lib->validate_ipn())) {
    $this->db->query( 'update users set users_money=users_money+212345, users_credits=users_credits+2123 WHERE users_id=' . $item );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's safe**

In `Paypal_Lib.php` file `validate_ipn()` method will send the `POST` data(received to ipn method) to paypal server

```
if (isset($_POST))
    {
        foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value)
        {       // str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $value)
                // put line feeds back to CR+LF as that's how PayPal sends them out
                // otherwise multi-line data will be rejected as INVALID

            $value = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $value);
            $this->ipn_data[$field] = $value;
            $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)).'&';

        }
    }
```

to verify whether that POST request came from paypal or other server.

Now Paypal will responds to verification request with `VERIFIED` or not. If it's verified means payment had made in paypal server So you can proceed to next steps.

If it don't respond with `VERIFIED` for validation request, it means that's the fake request(come other than paypal server).

Comment: Also, what I can do to make the POST variables safer? I know that its supposed only Paypal's servers to access them but still any suggestions? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You'll normaly want to check more than just gross payment. you might want to check currency type(dollars instead of yen for example), i always check that the purchase came from the correct user aswell, but basically you'll want to check everything you can.